# why app force closed in android 6 on Run

Tags: java, php, android, forceclose

hi i developed an app that use permission record audio and send to server.

in android 4 my app didnt have problem in running
but when i send app to App Store they say the app force closed in android 6.0

this is my logcat when run the app:

```
  io.fabric.sdk.android.g.a(InitializationTask.java:28) 
                                                 at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.a$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
    05-19 23:12:35.600 2141-2179/? E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
    05-19 23:12:36.100 2141-2141/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.cloudtech.ads.core.AdGuardService', referenced from method com.cloudtech.ads.core.CTService.b
    05-19 23:12:36.220 646-891/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
    05-19 23:12:36.240 646-2113/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.net.NetworkScoreManager', referenced from method wpj.a
    05-19 23:12:36.240 646-2113/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.net.NetworkScoreManager', referenced from method wpj.c
    05-19 23:13:01.150 1554-1591/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.160 1554-1591/? E/Finsky: [86] com.google.android.finsky.deviceconfig.k.a(15): Unable to fetch checkin consistency token: GooglePlayServices is unavailable 2
    05-19 23:13:01.230 1554-1945/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.250 1554-1554/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.250 1554-2670/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.290 1554-1554/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.300 1554-2140/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.310 1554-1554/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.x.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
    05-19 23:13:01.400 1554-1617/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.400 1554-2667/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:01.400 1554-2667/? E/Finsky: [121] com.google.android.finsky.deviceconfig.k.a(15): Unable to fetch checkin consistency token: GooglePlayServices is unavailable 2
    05-19 23:13:01.480 1554-1554/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.content.pm.PackageInstaller$SessionParams', referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.bz.a
    05-19 23:13:01.550 1554-1620/? E/Finsky: [101] com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.bj.a(76): Deferred uninstall works only for L+
    05-19 23:13:01.560 1554-1620/? E/Finsky: [101] com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.aa.a(3): Can't schedule deferred install. No modules found.
    05-19 23:13:02.450 1554-1621/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:02.450 1554-2700/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    05-19 23:13:33.440 171-3242/? E/AudioSink: received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
    05-19 23:13:33.440 2082-2082/myapp.apps.goo.myapp E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
    05-19 23:13:37.760 3327-3327/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method com.facebook.a.a.a.a
    05-19 23:13:37.790 3327-3327/? E/b: Starting ANR detector for process: com.facebook.lite
    05-19 23:13:37.810 646-1679/? E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Provided calling package not found: com.google.android.apps.photos



 please help
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: if your app is only intended to be run on Android 4.0, it seems to me you  need to make sure your apk is _only_ targeting that version (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element, https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms). Otherwise, you'd have to build your app against the version that crashed and debug the issue